# Disable file view expanding on CMD

Tags: intellij-idea, accessibility

When click ⌘ when the cursor is in a file, intellij shows this large scrollable zoomed in view of that file in a box at the top of the file:

[image]

I assume it's an accessibility feature that I accidentally enabled. Any idea how to disable this?

Comment: That is a macOS accessibility feature. Has nothing to do with IntelliJ directly.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-zoom-settings-for-accessibility-mh40579/mac

Answer (score 0):

As Basil Bourque said this is a mac feature - hover text.